# Building a traveling bike, frames and components: where to buy in Europe

Tags: frames, parts, touring, europe

I am about to either buy either build a bike for medium-long travels, and I am struggling with differences between the european and american market offer (I live in France). Talking about the beautiful salsa marrakesh, which really looks like a perfect deal for my needs, the gap between the american price in dollars and the european price is strong (frame 650$ vs 750€, bike 1650$ vs 2000€). Hence, I am wondering if someone of you knows a good european Salsa reseller with fair prices, or US seller that delivers overseas. Another option I am considering (to avoid expensive rim brakes) is the Surly long haul, but any suggestions in that direction are most welcome.

About components, the only all-covering european website that I know is bike-components.de, which is mainly focused around mtb and road bikes. While I surely can manage to combine pieces to find a good solution anyway, I'd like to know if there is a components online marketplace which mostly deals with traveling bikes and offers pieces directly on that purpose.

in a line: what's the online reference marketplace for components and frames for european bike travelers?

Comment: On this stack, we don't do specific product, or dealer recommendations because the info gets out of date.  Instead consider your needs... consider parts availability if/when you break down in some charming little village.   Forget the american pricing - its not relevant to you unless you're importing, which seems a shame given you live in the cycling continent already.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Lorenzo. As Criggie says, this question will probably be closed; do read the [help] to see how to use this site, and also use the search feature to see if you're question has already been addressed. You should be able to reformulate your question, but you'll also need to specify what you mean by *medium-long travels*. That could mean anything 50km to 5000km.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm sorry if the questions is out of rules boundaries, in that case, I'll peacefully accept the closing verdict! With medium-long travels I mean sort of what @andy256 wrote, from 200 km weekends to 2000+ km vacations abroad, i.e. comfortable on the long run, resilient to weather/sand, easy to repair-replace components.

Answer (score 1):

European prices always include VAT, and US prices are typically announced without sales tax (or customs, if you really intend to order from US). Once you add the sales tax, the prices are closer.

Generally, you will pay extra for a brand that is commonly not available in Europe. In addition to Surly, Thorn is easily available in Europe from UK and cheaper than Salsa.